# How to fill an object into specific properties of another object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping

I have an object a and i want to map the values of a into another object andoridConfig such that splashLdpi will have value of what   120x120 has i mean the url,splashMdpi will have value of what 160x160 has,splashHdpi will have a value of what 240x240 has and so on.

```
a = {
    "120x120": [
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/zopping-staging-uploads/120x120/20211221/wallpaperflarecomwallpaper-20211221-104553.jpg"
    ],
    "160x160": [
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/zopping-staging-uploads/160x160/20211221/wallpaperflarecomwallpaper-20211221-104553.jpg"
    ],
    "240x240": [
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/zopping-staging-uploads/240x240/20211221/wallpaperflarecomwallpaper-20211221-104553.jpg"
    ],
    "320x320": [
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/zopping-staging-uploads/320x320/20211221/wallpaperflarecomwallpaper-20211221-104553.jpg"
    ],
    "480x480": [
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/zopping-staging-uploads/480x480/20211221/wallpaperflarecomwallpaper-20211221-104553.jpg"
    ],
    "640x640": [
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/zopping-staging-uploads/640x640/20211221/wallpaperflarecomwallpaper-20211221-104553.jpg"
    ]
}

"androidAppConfig": {
    "playStoreServiceAccount": "https://storage.googleapis.com/zopping-uploads/originals/20211020/iclaunchercircle-20211020-112456.png",
    "fbServiceAccount": "https://storage.googleapis.com/zopping-uploads/originals/20211020/iclaunchercircle-20211020-112456.png",
    "icon512x512": "https://storage.googleapis.com/zopping-uploads/originals/20211020/iclaunchercircle-20211020-112456.png",
    "banner1024x500": "https://storage.googleapis.com/zopping-uploads/originals/20211020/iclaunchercircle-20211020-112456.png",
    "iconMdpiCircle": "https://storage.googleapis.com/zopping-uploads/originals/20211020/iclaunchercircle-20211020-112456.png",
    "iconMdpiSquare": "https://storage.googleapis.com/zopping-uploads/originals/20211020/iclaunchersq-20211020-112533.png",
    "iconHdpiCircle": "https://storage.googleapis.com/zopping-uploads/originals/20211020/iclaunchercircle-20211020-112842.png",
    "iconHdpiSquare": "https://storage.googleapis.com/zopping-uploads/originals/20211020/iclaunchersq-20211020-112946.png",
    "iconXhdpiCircle": "https://storage.googleapis.com/zopping-uploads/originals/20211020/iclaunchercircle-20211020-112201.png",
    "iconXhdpiSquare": "https://storage.googleapis.com/zopping-uploads/originals/20211020/iclaunchersq-20211020-112251.png",
    "iconXxhdpiCircle": "https://storage.googleapis.com/zopping-uploads/originals/20211020/iclaunchercircle-20211020-111829.png",
    "iconXxhdpiSquare": "https://storage.googleapis.com/zopping-uploads/originals/20211020/iclaunchersq-20211020-111956.png",
    "iconXxxhdpiCircle": "https://storage.googleapis.com/zopping-uploads/originals/20211020/iclaunchercircle-20211020-111431.png",
    "iconXxxhdpiSquare": "https://storage.googleapis.com/zopping-uploads/originals/20211020/iclaunchersq-20211020-111631.png",
    "splashLdpi": "https://storage.googleapis.com/zopping-uploads/originals/20211020/splash-20211020-112750.webp",
    "splashMdpi": "https://storage.googleapis.com/zopping-uploads/originals/20211020/splash-20211020-112645.webp",
    "splashHdpi": "https://storage.googleapis.com/zopping-uploads/originals/20211020/splash-20211020-113200.webp",
    "splashXhdpi": "https://storage.googleapis.com/zopping-uploads/originals/20211020/splash-20211020-112353.webp",
    "splashXxhdpi": "https://storage.googleapis.com/zopping-uploads/originals/20211020/splash-20211020-112053.webp",
    "splashXxxhdpi": "https://storage.googleapis.com/zopping-uploads/originals/20211020/splash-20211020-111724.webp"
  },
```

How do i acheive it?
I am thinking of extracting all the urls from object a into an array first and then somehow use that to fill androidAppConfig.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your mapping logic. Can you please provide an expected output for it?